# Comment box combining facebook and individual login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-comments, comments

I want to integrate a comment box to my website.
I've searched for several hours and I'm really confused now.

Is there a possibility to use the facebook comment box plugin and a login system which already exists for my website?

It would be nice to have both advantages.
On one hand the direct posts on the user walls on facebook.
And on the other hand an alternative for users, who don't have a facebook account or who don't want to post with their real names.

It would also be nice if there is a third party alternative which combines these things

Best regards and thank you for your answers
Martin